# Im not able to see model properties in a dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form that allows the user to fill out fields to create a ticket (Support ticket). These fields are mapped to a model called TicketModel. Now, in the form I have 2 buttons One that creates the ticket (submits the form) and another (Create And Close Ticket) that opens up a dialog and allows the user to enter some more information upon closure of ticket. Specifically they are entering the Start and end date as well as a description of what they did to resolve the issue.

The create button works fine. but when I click on the Close ticket within the dialog I noticed that the Model properties (StartDate, EndDate and Description) of the fields that were filled out in the dialog box are not in the TicketModel param when my CreateTicket action method is called (They are null).

Below is my relevent code sample.

The CreateTicket Partial View

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxCreateTicket", "Home",
new { id = "CreateTicketForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" },
new AjaxOptions
{
    OnBegin = "OnBegin",
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
    OnFailure = "OnFailure"
}))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please correct the following errors:")
<fieldset>

    <legend>TicketModel</legend>

      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserCreated)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserCreated)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserDisplayName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserDisplayName)
    </div>
// Remaining form fields omitted for brevity

</fieldset>

<div id="closeDialog" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="display: none;">
    @Html.Partial("_CloseNewTicketComment", Model)
</div>

}
```

Here is the partialView that gets put in the close dialog

```
@model HelpDesk.Web.Models.TicketModel

<script>
// wire up datetimepicker
$(function () {
    $(".date-picker").datetimepicker({
        timepicker: true,
        formatDate: 'm/d/Y',
        formatTime: 'h:i a',
        format: 'm/d/y h:i a',
        validateOnBlur: false,
        scrollInput: false,
        step: 15
    });
});


</script>

@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please correct the following errors:")
<div class="label">
Comment:
</div>
<div style="clear:both;height:10px" />
<div class="editor-field" id="closeTextBox">
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CommentModel.Description, new { @id =     "CloseDescription" })
</div>
<div style="clear:both;height:10px" />

<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateWorkStarted)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateWorkStarted, new { @class = "date-picker", @style = "width: 160px;" })
</div>
<div style="clear:both; height:10px" />

<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateClosed)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateClosed, new { @class = "date-picker",     @style = "width: 160px;" })
</div>

<div>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserCreated)
</div>
<div style="clear:both; height:10px" />
```

My Javascript from the CreateTicket partial View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userLookupData = '';
var thisRedactorCreate = '';

// wire up datetimepicker
$(function () {
    $(".date-picker").datetimepicker({
        timepicker: true,
        formatDate: 'm/d/Y',
        formatTime: 'h:i a',
        format: 'm/d/y h:i a',
        validateOnBlur: false,
        scrollInput: false,
        step: 15
    });
});

function OnBegin() {
progressDialogOpen();
}

function OnSuccess() {
//thisRedactorCreate.redactor("destroy");
progressDialogClose();
$('#CreateTicketForm').clearForm();
showSuccessDialog(0);
}

function OnFailure() {
progressDialogClose();
}

// This is the click event jquery that opens the dialog
    $("#CreateCloseButton").click(function () {

        // change IsCreateAndClose boolean because this ticket is going to be closed 
        // upon creation
        $("#IsCreateAndClose").val("true")

        if ($('form').valid())
        {
            $(".validation-summary-errors")
            .removeClass("validation-summary-errors")
            .addClass("validation-summary-valid");


            $("#closeDialog").dialog({
                width: 525,
                height: 500,
                modal: true,
                resizable: true,
                title: 'Close Ticket',
                close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                buttons:{
                    "Close Ticket": function () {
                        if ($('form').valid())
                        {
                            $('form').submit();
                            $('#closeDialog').dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })
```

The ActionMethod that gets called on the ajax call

```
        [ValidateInput(false)]//this is necessary because we are posting HTML
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AjaxCreateTicket(TicketModel ticketModel)
        {

            // If this action is not being called from the create and close dialog
            // we need to remove the data annotations for the descriptiong property of the commmentModel.
            if (!ticketModel.IsCreateAndClose)
            {
                ModelState.Remove("CommentModel.Description");
            }


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                bool ticketCreated = false;

                try
                {

                    Ticket ticket = new Ticket();

                    //form collection
                    ticket.Title = ticketModel.Title;
                    ticket.UserEmail = ticketModel.UserEmail;
                    ticket.Description = ticketModel.Description;
                    ticket.UserComputerName = ticketModel.UserComputerName;
// Irrelevant code omitted for brevity.
```

If I set a breakpoint in the action method and add a watch to the TicketModel object. I noticed that the DateWorkStarted, DateClosed and The Description field from the commentModel are null. I have been looking around for the past couple of days to try and figure out why this is with no luck. Does anyone have any ideas of what I could be doing wrong (or not doing at all)?

Comment: Where are your buttons?

Comment: Can you show us the code for TicketModel?

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML for the inputs in question?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your code form is 'submit'-ted correctly, despite form's definition is omitted and it is not clear where it posts. Perhaps it posts to the AjaxCreateTicket action despite I do not see this action decorated with [HttpPost]?

If so, it looks like there's a problem with the ModelBinder. (Unfortunately your model is not shown as well). This is why I can only suspect that **your model defines public fields instead of public properties**. MopelBinder works with properties only and ignores fields, no mater access to them - public, internal, protected. Privates do not count at all.

Of course, *I might be completely wrong* since important parts are missing from your code. If you post your model as a minimum, it'd poor some more light on what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of working on this with a co-worker we were able to get it working. The only thing is I don't remember what exactly we did to get it working (blame it on many late hours) but it seems to be working now.

Thanks for all the input on this though.